# I don't understand how this concentration problem is modeled.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is the problem:

[image]

Ignore the part about inverses. I got that. I am confused why C is modeled this way. I don't get where the 100 + n came from. When I look up concentration and mixture problems, I get problems that are not represented as rational functions, like this:

[image]

Can someone walk me through how this function was created from the information provided?

Answer (score 1):

The concentration is the amount of solute divided by the total volume. We started out with a 20% solution and 100ml, so 20 of the 100ml was acid. We added $n$ ml, and that solution was 40% acid, so we added $0.4n$ ml of acid and $n$ ml of solute. In the end, the total volume was $100+n$ and the total solute was $20+0.4n$.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I'm not a chemistry person, so words like "concentration"  and "solution" were confusing me. Seeing concentration as a ratio of a solute (aka the substance we are interested in) and the total volume, makes so much more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

ok so the concentration is given as:
$$conc=\frac{mass\,of\,salt}{total\,mass}$$
but what you have to remember is that when we add a mass of salt its add to both the top and bottom of the fraction. We have:
$$m_{salt}=20\times\frac{20}{100}$$
$$m_{total}=20$$
so if we add an amount of salt we want:
$$\frac{20\times0.2+y}{20+y}=0.25$$
now rearrange and solve for y

Answer (score 0):

The formula makes more sense if it's written like this.
$$C = \frac{0.2(100) + 0.4n}{1.0(100)+1.0n}$$